# Does the http client of angular2 throw an exception if status in Response is not in 2XX series?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

While doing a `map` for the returned `Observable` from an `HTTP` request if the `status code` of the response doesn't belong to the `2xx` series the control reaches the `catch` block on itself and doesn't even come under the success callback of the `map`. Is this how it is supposed to work? Where can I find a relevant code for this?
Am I correct in saying that its the `status code` in the response which makes it go to the `catch` (unless obviously, I don't have an error inside my map itself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Angular's HTTP implementation examines the status code and emits an error from the observable if an unsucessful status code is received.

See the `isSuccess` method in [`http_utils.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.x/packages/http/src/http_utils.ts#L33):

```ts
export const isSuccess = (status: number): boolean => (status >= 200 && status < 300);
```

And the `XHRConnection` implementation in [`xhr_backend.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.x/packages/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L87-L94):

```ts
const response = new Response(responseOptions);
response.ok = isSuccess(status);
if (response.ok) {
  responseObserver.next(response);
  // TODO(gdi2290): defer complete if array buffer until done
  responseObserver.complete();
  return;
}
responseObserver.error(response);
```